# Function argument returning void or non-void type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am in the middle of writing some generic code for a future library. I came across the following problem inside a template function. Consider the code below:

```
template<class F>
auto foo(F &&f) {
    auto result = std::forward<F>(f)(/*some args*/);
    //do some generic stuff
    return result;
}
```

It will work fine, unless I pass to it a function that returns `void` like:

```
foo([](){});
```

Now, of course, I could use some `std::enable_if` magic to check the return type and perform specialization for a function returning `void` that looks like this:

```
template<class F, class = /*enable if stuff*/>
void foo(F &&f) {
    std::forward<F>(f)(/*some args*/);
    //do some generic stuff
}
```

But that would awfully duplicate code for actually logically equivalent functions. Can this be done easily in a generic way for both `void`-returning and non-`void`-returning functions in a elegant way?

EDIT:
there is data dependency between function `f()` and generic stuff I want to do, so I do not take code like this into account:

```
template<class F>
auto foo(F &&f) {
    //do some generic stuff
    return std::forward<F>(f)(/*some args*/);
}
```

Comment: offtopic: this `std::forward` is misused. It should be used only if argument can be moved to next function/template. It doesn't break anything here it is just boilerplate.

Comment: After your edit: How can this possibly work with `void` return types? Either you assign the return value to `result` or you leave it. `auto return = some_void_func()` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MarekR what if function object with rvalue only overload of `operator()` is passed? Will it work without `forward`?

Comment: OK fair point, it is possible that someone can define such operator. This is quite unusual, but possible, so `std::forward` can have sense here.

Comment: related proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you can place the "some generic stuff" in the destructor of a `bar` class (inside a security try/catch block, if you're not sure that doesn't throw exceptions, as pointed by Drax), you can simply write

```
template <typename F>
auto foo (F &&f)
 {
   bar b;

   return std::forward<F>(f)(/*some args*/);
 }
```

So the compiler compute `f(/*some args*/)`, exec the destructor of `b` and return the computed value (or nothing).

Observe that `return func();`, where `func()` is a function returning `void`, is perfectly legal.

Comment: bonus tip: the "generic stuff" should better not throw anything

Comment: And what if it does throw something? What if you need to propagate that exception?

Comment: @Barry - yes: this is another limit of this solution.

Answer (score 9):

Some specialization, somewhere, is necessary. But the goal here is to avoid specializing the function itself. However, you can specialize a helper class.

Tested with gcc 9.1 with `-std=c++17`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct return_value {


    T val;

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    return_value(F &&f, Args && ...args)
        : val{f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}
    {
    }

    T value() const
    {
        return val;
    }
};

template<>
struct return_value<void> {

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    return_value(F &&f, Args && ...args)
    {
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void value() const
    {
    }
};

template<class F>
auto foo(F &&f)
{
    return_value<decltype(std::declval<F &&>()(2, 4))> r{f, 2, 4};

    // Something

    return r.value();
}

int main()
{
    foo( [](int a, int b) { return; });

    std::cout << foo( [](int a, int b) { return a+b; }) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: *"Some specialization, somewhere, is necessary."* not with a `Finally` raii code, as proposed in another answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 - but the other answer has a great limit: if the "some generic stuff" needs the value computed by `f()` (if not `void`) I don't see a way to avoid a specialization somewhere. I suspect that Sam's answer is better than mine.

Comment: This incurs an unconditional extra copy.

Comment: An extra copy could be avoided by having `foo()` return the helper object itself. Which will necessitate changing the callers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's... not a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this, in my opinion, is to actually change the way you call your possibly-void-returning functions. Basically, we change the ones that return `void` to instead return some class type `Void` that is, for all intents and purposes, the same thing and no users really are going to care.

```
struct Void { };
```

All we need to do is to wrap the invocation. The following uses C++17 names (`std::invoke` and `std::invoke_result_t`) but they're all implementable in C++14 without too much fuss:

```
// normal case: R isn't void
template <typename F, typename... Args, 
    typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<R>::value, int> = 0>
R invoke_void(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// special case: R is void
template <typename F, typename... Args, 
    typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<R>::value, int> = 0>
Void invoke_void(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    // just call it, since it doesn't return anything
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // and return Void
    return Void{};
}
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can just directly write the code you wanted to write to begin with, in the way you wanted to write it:

```
template<class F>
auto foo(F &&f) {
    auto result = invoke_void(std::forward<F>(f), /*some args*/);
    //do some generic stuff
    return result;
}
```

And you don't have to either shove all your logic in a destructor or duplicate all of your logic by doing specialization. At the cost of `foo([]{})` returning `Void` instead of `void`, which isn't much of a cost.

And then if [Regular Void](https://wg21.link/p0146) is ever adopted, all you have to do is swap out `invoke_void` for `std::invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a void function (or non-returning value function) in C++ that will accept two integer values as parameters and will display the numbers between those two numbers inclusive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34322493)

Answer (score -1):

In case you need to use `result` (in non-void cases) in "some generic stuff", I propose a `if constexpr` based solution (so, unfortunately, not before C++17).

Not really elegant, to be honest.

First of all, detect the "true return type" of `f` (given the arguments)

```
using TR_t = std::invoke_result_t<F, As...>;
```

Next a `constexpr` variable to see if the returned type is `void` (just to simplify a little the following code)

```
constexpr bool isVoidTR { std::is_same_v<TR_t, void> };
```

Now we define a (potentially) "fake return type": `int` when the true return type is `void`, the `TR_t` otherwise

```
using FR_t = std::conditional_t<isVoidTR, int, TR_t>;
```

Then we define the a smart pointer to the result value as pointer to the "fake return type" (so `int` in void case)

```
std::unique_ptr<FR_t>  pResult;
```

Passing through a pointer, instead of a simple variable of type "fake return type", we can operate also when `TR_t` isn't default constructible or not assignable (limits, pointed by Barry (thanks), of the first version of this answer).

Now, using `if constexpr`, the two case to exec `f` (this, IMHO, is the ugliest part because we have to write two times the same `f` invocation)

```
if constexpr ( isVoidTR )
   std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<As>(args)...);
else
   pResult.reset(new TR_t{std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<As>(args)...)});
```

After this, the "some generic stuff" that can use `result` (in non-void cases) and also `isVoidTR).

To conclude, another `if constexpr`

```
if constexpr ( isVoidTR )
   return;
else
   return *pResult;
```

As pointed by Barry, this solution has some important downsides because (not `void` cases)

- require an allocation
- require an extra copy in correspondence of the `return`
- doesn't works at all if the `TR_t` (the type returned by `f()`) is a reference type

Anyway, the following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename ... As>
auto foo (F && f, As && ... args)
 {
   // true return type
   using TR_t = std::invoke_result_t<F, As...>;

   constexpr bool isVoidTR { std::is_same_v<TR_t, void> };

   // (possibly) fake return type
   using FR_t = std::conditional_t<isVoidTR, int, TR_t>;

   std::unique_ptr<FR_t>  pResult;

   if constexpr ( isVoidTR )
      std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<As>(args)...);
   else
      pResult.reset(new TR_t{std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<As>(args)...)});

   // some generic stuff (potentially depending from result,
   // in non-void cases)

   if constexpr ( isVoidTR )
      return;
   else
      return *pResult;
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo([](){});

   //auto a { foo([](){}) };  // compilation error: foo() is void

   auto b { foo([](auto a0, auto...){ return a0; }, 1, 2l, 3ll) };

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b), int> );

 }
```

Comment: This solution imposes default construction and assignment as requirements (in addition to lots of boilerplate). The underlying idea, swapping out `void` for a regular type, is a good one though - see my answer for a better way to implement that idea.

Comment: @Barry - Yes, this solution require a lots of boilerplate but permit to use the computed value in the "generic stuff"; my other solution is trivially simple but the result is unusable; taking this in account, I think the boilerplate is justifiable. You're right about default contruction and assignment; i was thinking of add a caveat in the answer but there is a simple way (a little boilerplate more) to avoid this problem; answer modified. Anyway, I find your solution interesting but really different because change the signature of the function (`foo()` never return `void` anymore).

Comment: ... and now it requires an extra copy and a full allocation!

Comment: @Barry - yes, but avoid the problem of the default construction and assignment; the extra copy is about a pointer.

Comment: The extra copy is not a pointer, it's the full object. This inhibits RVO.

Comment: @Barry - sorry, which extra copy do you refer?

Comment: The return object, `return *pResult;` That's a copy.

Comment: @Barry - "Also you can't "yes, but" an extra allocation..." - why not?

Comment: No, there was no extra copy in the original code. Copy elision applies.

Comment: You can't just add an extra allocation/deallocation because it makes it convenient to solve a metaprogramming puzzle. That is a huge performance hit that's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Barry - copy elision... yes, you're right. But isn't an extra copy (in `void`/`Void` case) also in your solution?

Comment: All this because it's supposedly "really different" to return `void` instead of `Void`? It's actually not different at all, neither conceptually nor practically. A unit type is a unit type, many languages have them more directly -- we just happen not to.

Comment: No, there's no extra copy. And `Void` is an empty type anyway so even if there were...?

Comment: When I say the allocation is totally unnecessary, Sam's solution demonstrates one way of doing this.

Comment: @Barry - I disagree: IMHO, you can't change the function signature to solve a problem of this type.

Comment: @Barry - OK: it's possible avoid an allocation and probably the allocation is heavy. Said this, with all defects (IMHO, the ugliest is the repetition of the `f` call) I think that this way can be of interest for someone interested in this problem.

Comment: Of course you can change the signature. If the caller is passing you a void function, they're not expecting a return anyway. Compare that to the upside of being able to write normal code, AND be able to properly handle exceptions, AND avoid any extra copies. Far from being a downside, returning `Void` is it's own benefit since it lets this function compose too. I've been using this pattern as a basic building block of several libraries and not one time have I ever _needed_ the return type to stay `void`.

Comment: Incidentally, this also won't work if `TR_t` is a reference type.

Comment: @Barry - "Incidentally, this also won't work if `TR_t` is a reference type"; yes, this is a great limits I dind't noticed; thanks. Answer modified adding your points (correct it if I've misunderstand something).