# C++ compile code depending on the concrete type of auto

Tags: c++

I have a C++ piece of code

```
auto returnvalue = m_func(x, y, z);
```

where the type of m_func depends on a template parameter. Afterwards I deal with the `returnvalue` which works fine until `m_func` is a function returning void. But I need a mechanism which calls

```
m_func(x,y,z)
```

if the return value of m_func is void and  the above version is not. Overall in pseudo code it need to look like

```
if ( returnvalue of m_func is void ) 
     call m_func directly
else 
     auto retval = m_func(...) 
     handle the return value
```

How can these be done with C++11/14?

Edit:

m_func is either:

```
void func(type1 arg1, type2 arg, ...)
```

or

```
std::tuple<...> func(type1 arg1, type2 arg, ...)
```

Comment: What is the template type of `m_func` based off? The arguments?

Comment: It really depends.  Can you show us how you are calling `my_func` (what context it is in)?

Comment: What does **handle the return value** mean? Create a [mcve]

Comment: @eerorika Shouldn't matter in the context of OP's question.

Comment: @sweenish it does matter (probably). The solution may be different depending on it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725427/handling-a-void-variable-in-a-templatized-function-in-c11, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56256640/function-argument-returning-void-or-non-void-type

Comment: Doubt it. This is a SFINAE problem based on the return type of m_func, where we only care if it is void or not. What I'd rather see is m_func itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whereas C++17 has `if constexpr` to handle it simply, C++11/C++14 has to use some overload to handle it via SFINAE or tag dispatching or specialization, follow up a tag dispatching version:

```
void internal_impl(std::true_type/*, ... */) {
    m_func(x, y, z);
}
void internal_impl(std::false_type/*, ... */) {
    auto value = m_func(x, y, z);

    foo(value);
}

void internal(/*... */) {
    internal_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,
                                         std::is_void<decltype(m_func(x, y, z))>::value>{}
                  /*, ...*/);
}
```

Comment: I had to add a `{} ` to `std::integral_constant<bool,                                         std::is_void<decltype(m_func(x, y, z))>::value>` and then it works like a charm and it is still readable by our non C++ programmers.

Comment: missing `{}` added.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to C++17, you can use template specialisation:

```
template<class R>
struct handle {
    template<class F>
    static void the_return_value(F m_func) {
        auto retval = m_func(x, y, z);
        // handle the return value
    }
};

template<>
struct handle<void> {
    template<class F>
    static void the_return_value(F m_func) {
        m_func(x, y, z);
    }
};

// usage
using R = decltype(m_func(x, y, z));
handle<R>::the_return_value(m_func);
```

In C++17, you can use `if constexpr` instead:

```
using R = decltype(m_func(x, y, z));
if constexpr (std::is_void_v<R>) {
    m_func(x, y, z);
} else {
    auto retval = m_func(x, y, z);
    // handle the return value
}
```